# Numpy structured array performance

Tags: performance, numpy, structured-array

I've got a look-up problem that boils down to the following situation.
Three columns with positive integers. For some value `i`, which values in `'column_3'` have a value in `'column_1'` below `i` and a value in `'column_2'` above `i`?

```
import numpy as np

rows = 1e6
i = 5e8

ts = np.zeros((rows,), dtype=[('column_1','int64'),('column_2','int64'),('column_3','int64')])
ts['column_1'] = np.random.randint(low=0,high=1e9,size=rows)
ts['column_2'] = np.random.randint(low=0,high=1e9,size=rows)
ts['column_3'] = np.random.randint(low=0,high=1e9,size=rows)
```

This is the operation I'd like to optimize:

```
%%timeit
a = ts[(ts['column_1'] < i)&(ts['column_2'] > i)]['column_3']
```

Is there anything I'm overlooking that could make this faster?
Would be grateful for any advice!!

Comment: My guess is that 3 separate arrays would do as well, but we'd have to do some timings to be sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assigning your 3 arrays to `A,B,C` at creation as well:

```
In [3]: %%timeit
   ...: a = ts[(ts['column_1'] < i)&(ts['column_2'] > i)]['column_3']
   ...: 
22.5 ms ± 838 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
In [4]: %%timeit
   ...: a = C[(A < i)&(B > i)]
   ...: 
   ...: 
9.36 ms ± 15 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Using `a,b,c = ts['column_1'],ts['column_2'],ts['column_3']` instead falls in between.

Those are variants and timings you can play with.  As I can see it just minor differences due to indexing differences.  Nothing like an order of magnitude difference.